# Calling Fortran functions which return KIND=10 complex values from C++

Tags: c++, fortran, g++, gfortran, mixed-programming

I have a bunch of old F77 source code (usually compiled on a `x86_64` with `gfortran -std=legacy`).
It contains quite a few functions in form:

```
      double complex function f(x, y, i)
      double precision x, y
      integer i
      f = cmplx(x, y) * i
      return
      end
```

I need to call these functions from some C++ code (usually compiled on a `x86_64` with `g++`).

1. It works with the default Fortran `KIND=8`:

   ```cpp
   extern "C" { std::complex<double> f_(double *x, double *y, int *i); }
   ```
2. It works when I enforce the default Fortran `KIND=4` using the `-freal-8-real-4` option:

   ```cpp
   extern "C" { std::complex<float> f_(float *x, float *y, int *i); }
   ```
3. It works when I enforce the default Fortran `KIND=16` using the `-freal-8-real-16` option (and in C++ `#include <quadmath.h>`):

   ```cpp
   extern "C" { __complex128 f_(__float128 *x, __float128 *y, int *i); }
   ```

   To my surprise, in this case, it also seems to work with (the returned value is in `*z`):

   ```cpp
   extern "C" { void f_(__complex128 *z, __float128 *x, __float128 *y, int *i); }
   ```

   Which of these two above prototypes is the (more?) proper one?
4. My problem is that I cannot get it working with my desired default Fortran `KIND=10` using the `-freal-8-real-10` option. Inside of Fortran, the `kind`, `precision`, `range` and `sizeof` return values which directly correspond to the C++ `long double`. So, I tried:

   ```cpp
   extern "C" { std::complex<long double> f_(long double *x, long double *y, int *i); }
   extern "C" { void f_(std::complex<long double> *z, long double *x, long double *y, int *i); }
   extern "C" { void f_(long double *x, long double *y, int *i, std::complex<long double> *z); }
   ```

   But I cannot get it working at all.

   Maybe I need to add some special flags to `gfortran` and / or `g++` calls in order to let C++ retrieve Fortran `KIND=10` complex values?
   Note: I don't think I can use `-ff2c`.

**Update (2020.08.04)**: I have been able to fool the C++ compiler so that it seems to generate proper code for any Fortran `KIND=4,8,10`. The trick is to use the ISO C99 `_Complex` in C++ (note: this trick is required only for `KIND=10`, but it actually works for `KIND=4,8`, too):

```cpp
#include <complex.h>
#define C99KIND long double /* it can be "float", "double" or "long double" */
extern "C" { C99KIND _Complex f_(C99KIND *x, C99KIND *y, int *i); }
```

Note that, in C++, you cannot use e.g. `long double complex` but fortunately `long double _Complex` is still fine.

The usability of the ISO C99 `_Complex` in C++ is rather limited. For example, with `-std=c++11` (or newer) even the most basic `creal*` and `cimag*` functions disappear.

So, the best idea is to immediately copy the returned value into some standard C++ templated complex variable, e.g using something like (note: `f_` returns `C99KIND _Complex`):

```cpp
std::complex<C99KIND> z = f_(&x, &y, &i);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that, even though 80-bit FPU calculations may be used for `long double`, `sizeof(long double)` [is 16 in my case](https://godbolt.org/z/a7bnvv), therefore the storage layout does not match that's of Fortran. Don't know if there is any switch to store `long double` as 10-byte.

Comment: Why do you want Kind=10? But the way to do this is not via picking random kinds and compiler flags, but the standard method defined by Fortran

Comment: Yes, the `sizeof(long double)` is 16 in C++ but the same value is returned by FORTRAN for `REAL(KIND=10)`. I think there is no problem in using ordinary "real" values, just the "complex" makes to problem.

I want to use `KIND=10` because it a very good compromise between the achieved precision and the required calculation time.

Comment: BTW. Also the sizes of the corresponding "complex" variables agree between the two compilers (they both return 32 = 2 * 16) and they both use 80-bit FPU calculations for the "real" and "imaginary" parts.

Comment: @DanielLangr, gfotran's `REAL(10)` is padded to 16 bytes, and for a bonus tip.  gfortran's `REAL(10)` is the type that matches gcc/g++'s `long double` on x86_64.  `REAL(16)` and `__float128` are the types associated with GCC's libquadmath (i.e., a software implementation of IEEE-754 binary128 type.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the job correctly, then learn how to actually use Fortran's kind type parameters and do a proper port of your Fortran code to `REAL(10)`.  Yes, I know `10` is not portable; we are however, discussing a particular Fortran processor.

Consider,

```
function f(x, y, i) result(r) bind(c, name='f')
  use iso_c_binding, only : ep => c_long_double
  implicit none
  complex(ep) r
  real(ep), intent(in), value :: x, y
  integer, intent(in), value :: i
  r = cmplx(x, y, ep) * i
end function f
```

and, since I don't do C++ but you should be able to update the C to your needs

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long double complex f(long double, long double, int);

int
main(void)
{
  int i;
  long double x, y;
  long double complex z;

  i = 42;
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
  printf("%.10Lf %.10Lf\n", x, y);

  z = f(x, y, i);
  x = creall(z);
  y = cimagl(z);
  printf("%.10Lf %.10Lf\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}

% gfortran -c a.f90
% gcc -o z b.c a.o -lm
% ./z
1.0000000000 2.0000000000
42.0000000000 84.0000000000
```

OP states that he cannot be bothered with a proper port of his/her Fortran code, and so therefore, must use a compiler option to magically (and yes it is magic) to do the port.  Here's an example

```
% cat a.f90
double complex function f(x, y, i)
  implicit none
  double precision :: x, y
  integer i
  f = cmplx(x, y) * i   ! cmplx my not do what you expect
end function f

% cat b.c
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long double complex f_(long double *, long double *, int *);

int
main(void)
{
  int i;
  long double x, y;
  long double complex z;

  i = 42;
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
  printf("%.10Lf %.10Lf\n", x, y);

  z = f_(&x, &y, &i);
  x = creall(z);
  y = cimagl(z);
  printf("%.10Lf %.10Lf\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}

% gfcx -c -freal-8-real-10 a.f90
% gcc -o z b.c a.o -lm
% ./z
1.0000000000 2.0000000000
42.0000000000 84.0000000000
```

Might as well go for the trifecta.  Here's the C++ code to go with the file a.f90 above in the second example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

extern "C" { std::complex<long double> f_(long double *, long double *, int *); }

int main()
{
  std::complex<long double> z;
  long double x, y;
  int i;

  i = 42;
  x = 1;
  y = 2;
  z = f_(&x, &y, &i);

  std::cout << z << '\n';
 }
```

Comment: Please. It is spelt Fortran. It has been officially for 30 years+

Comment: @francescalus, The example was composed in 5 minutes or so.  Whenever, I have a binding label on a function name I tend to include `ISO_C_BINDING`.  In hindsight, I should have used `c_long_double` for the kind type parameter instead of defining `ep`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Note, however, that your C++ example uses exactly what I originally tried (on Linux) and it either produces a "segfault" or one gets nonsense values (e.g. `(nan,nan)`). Fortunately, your another idea, to use the ISO C99 `_Complex` (shown in your C example), can also be applied in C++ and it seems to solve the problem (see my "update" above).

Comment: Interesting.   Must be a difference in a 32-bit OS vs 64-bit OS.